# How to extract request url w.r.t. response url when using link extractor in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some urls from pages using link extractor but I also need to know requested url against which response urls have been extracted.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ExtractSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Extract'
    allowed_domains = ["xyz.com"]
    start_urls = [a,b,c]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('xyz.com/s')), callback="parse_link", follow=False)]

    def parse_link(self, response):
        yield {"start_Url": "I want to know"(a or b or c) ,"response_url":response.url}
```

I believe here I cannot use request.meta to transfer the variable. please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.request.headers.get('referer')
```